# How to get predictions for each fold in 10-fold cross-validation of the best tuned hyperparameters using caret package in r?

Tags: r, r-caret

I was trying to run SVM model using 10-fold cross-validation with 3 repeats using the caret package in R. I want to get the prediction results of each fold using the best tuned hyperparameters. I am using the following code

```
# Load packages
library(mlbench)
library(caret)

# Load data
data(BostonHousing)

#Dividing the data into train and test set
set.seed(101)
sample <- createDataPartition(BostonHousing$medv, p=0.80, list = FALSE)
train <- BostonHousing[sample,]
test <- BostonHousing[-sample,]

control <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv', number=10, repeats=3, savePredictions=TRUE)
metric <- 'RMSE'

# Support Vector Machines (SVM) 
set.seed(101)
fit.svm <- train(medv~., data=train, method='svmRadial', metric=metric,
                 preProc=c('center', 'scale'), trControl=control)
fit.svm$bestTune
fit.svm$pred
```

`fit.svm$pred` giving me predictions using all combinations of the hyperparameters. But I want to have only the predictions using best-tuned hyperparameters for each 10-fold average of the repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve your goal is to subset `fit.svm$pred` using the hyper parameters in `fit.svm$bestTune`, and then aggregate the desired measure by CV replicates. I will perform this using `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
fit.svm$pred %>%
  filter(sigma == fit.svm$bestTune$sigma & C == fit.svm$bestTune$C) %>% #subset 
  mutate(fold = gsub("\\..*", "", Resample), #extract fold info from resample info
         rep = gsub(".*\\.(.*)", "\\1", Resample)) %>% #extract replicate info from resample info
  group_by(rep) %>% #group by replicate
  summarise(rmse = RMSE(pred, obs)) #aggregate the desired measure
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  rep    rmse
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Rep1   4.02
2 Rep2   3.96
3 Rep3   4.06
```

EDIT: if you dislike using regex, or just want to save a bit of typing you can use `dplyr::separate`:

```
fit.svm$pred %>%
  filter(sigma == fit.svm$bestTune$sigma & C == fit.svm$bestTune$C) %>%
  separate(Resample, c("fold", "rep"), "\\.") %>%
  group_by(rep) %>%
  summarise(rmse = RMSE(obs, pred))
```

EDIT2: in response to comment. To write observed and predicted values to a csv. file:

```
fit.svm$pred %>%
  filter(sigma == fit.svm$bestTune$sigma & C == fit.svm$bestTune$C) %>%
  write.csv("predictions.csv")
```

Comment: I don't want the RMSE as output. I want the observed and predicted values using best tune parameter for each fold, so that I can calculate **standard deviation or standard error of prediction**. Using your code I am only able to see the observed and predicted values of first 10 samples. How to write it in .csv file?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am getting the desired output now. If it is possible to get the output as **standard deviation or standard error for every observation** average over the repeats will be of great help.

Comment: So you want standard deviation and error over the repeats but for what? For RMSE?

Comment: To measure the uncertainty of the model predictions. Actually, I will be using it for digital mapping of model uncertainties. I want to have the map of SE of model predictions or confidence interval will also serve the purpose. Is it possible to get **confidence interval for SVM predictions**. I know it is available for linear regression .

Comment: You would like to have confidence intervals for the predictions? I think you can do this via bootstrapping. I am not aware of any closed form calculation for estimating SVM confidence intervals. This is related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94845/how-to-estimate-confidence-level-for-svm-or-random-forest. If my comment is not helpful enough consider asking another question.